# Render Link in material ui Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I want to add my react-router links to `Drawer`. I tried this:

```
<Drawer width={200} open={this.state.drawerOpen} docked={false} onRequestChange={this.toggleDrawer}>
   <Link to="/businesspartners">
      <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this, false)}
                rightIcon={<CommunicationBusiness />}
      >
         Business Partners
      </MenuItem>
   </Link>
</Drawer>
```

My problem is that the link will render underlined (like the image below).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline style  `textDecoration: 'none'`  for the link.
`<Link>` gets rendered as a standard `<a>` tag, which is why we can apply textDecoration rule there.

```
<Drawer width={200} open={this.state.drawerOpen} docked={false} onRequestChange={this.toggleDrawer}>
   <Link to="/businesspartners" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
      <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this, false)}
                rightIcon={<CommunicationBusiness />}
      >
         Business Partners
      </MenuItem>
   </Link>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: I know this solution. But I suspected if I made a mistake because I was expecting the library to handle it.

Comment: You don't need any library to handle it. This is the way to go :). Link attribute belongs to the react-router library . All its specifications is handled by react-router and text-decoration isn't one of them.material-ui and react-router are two isolated libraries.

Comment: I meant material-ui library

Answer (score 15):

I had similar concerns with using styles directly and came across the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252439/522859

To summarize, use the component attribute on the ListItem:

```
<List>
   <ListItem button component={Link} to="https://www.google.com">
        <ListItemText primary="Google" />
   </ListItem>
</List>
```

The official docs cover it here: https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/

Comment: Brilliant! Works.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but maybe a new update in materialUI due to this is  not working,
There has some tweak as import from import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

so it will works

```
     import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

     <List>
      <ListItem button component={Link} href="/dsda">
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DashboardIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="DashBoard"/>
      </ListItem>
     </List>
```