# How to add a link to a List in material-ui 1.0?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The following messes with the onClick animation (the ListItem turns red):

```
<List>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <ListItem button>
       <ListItemText primary="Google" />
     </ListItem>
   </a>
 </List>
```

While adding the link inside ListItem, only makes the transition work if ListItemText is clicked, which is not what I want.
What is the correct way to add a link?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to make the `ListItem` a link by using the `component` prop:

```
<List>
  <ListItem button component="a" href="https://www.google.com">
    <ListItemText primary="Google" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

That way, the `ListItem` will be an anchor tag linking to the desired place, but still receive the appropriate styling so that there won't be any visual changes.

The behavior of the `component` prop is documented [here](https://material-ui-next.com/api/list-item/#props). Note that the `href` prop will be automatically passed to the anchor tag, as specified by the last line in the props documentation:

> Any other properties supplied will be spread to the root element.

Comment: A `ListItem` with `component="a"` and `href` works great for external links. For internal links it's better to use `component={Link}` with a `to` attribute.

Comment: Extending @BennyNeugebauer answer if  `href` is used it will reload the page so it shouldn't be used for some internal routes.

Answer (score 179):

to use with "react-router-dom"

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<ListItem button component={Link} to="/design">
```

the example is based in this section: [docs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library)

Comment: This is a good solution if you need to rely on Push-State URLs.

Comment: This should be the correct solution effective to the latest version of Material UI

Comment: What if I need some part of the list item to routable but not the whole thing? In my scenario I have some text that I want to be clickable, and then an exand chevron to view sections beneath that one

Comment: I don't really understand how this works; What does it technically mean if I add Link as a component property?

Comment: With Material UI 4.11.0, this solution doesn't work, at least for me. Getting " Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button: true; } & { alignItems?: "center" | "flex-start" | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; button?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'"

Comment: does this work for external links? seems it only routes internally!

Comment: Make sure to use `Link` from "react-router-dom" and not the MUI Component.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue but maybe a new update in materialUI due to this is not working, There has some tweak as import from import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

so it will works

```
 import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

 <List>
  <ListItem button component={Link} href="/dsda">
    <ListItemIcon>
      <DashboardIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="DashBoard"/>
  </ListItem>
 </List>
```

[Render Link in material ui Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466270/render-link-in-material-ui-drawer/67075275#67075275)

Answer (score 4):

For usage with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), this worked for me:

```
import Link from "next/link";

<List>
    <Link href="/myUrl" passHref>
        <ListItem button component="a">
            My Link Text
        </ListItem>
    </Link>
</List>
```

Answer (score 3):

For mui V5 + NextJS and if you want to have multiple children inside the list item (for example text and an icon) this worked for me:

```
import {
  Link,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
} from '@mui/material';
import NextLink from 'next/link';

<NextLink href="/some/route" passHref>
  <ListItem
    button
    component={Link}
  >
    <ListItemIcon>
      <SupportIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      primary="Support"
      secondary="Get super friendly support"
    ></ListItemText>
  </ListItem>
</NextLink>
```

This will give you real `a`-tags that still have nextjs-routing without page reloads.

Answer (score 2):

`ListItem`'s `button` prop is now **DEPRECATED** as you can see in [ListItem props (MUI API Docs)](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/#props)

This would be the updated version of the code proposed by @JulesDupont answer:

```js
<List>
  <ListItem>
    <ListItemButton component="a" href="https://www.google.com">
      <ListItemText primary="Google" />
    </ListItemButton>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
// material-ui components
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
// react-router
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
const ListItemLink = (props) => {
  const { icon, primary, to } = props;

  const renderLink = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      forwardRef((itemProps, ref) => (
        <RouterLink to={to} ref={ref} {...itemProps} />
      )),
    [to]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <ListItem button component={renderLink}>
        {icon ? <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon> : null}
        <ListItemText primary={primary} />
      </ListItem>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListItemLink;
```

It's actually available in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Link to="/categories">
          <ListItem key={index} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
            <ListItemButton
            >
              
              <ListItemText
              />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
```